# how to iterate through POST in Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

```
**some url modification** URL = 

public function imageupload($request.. blah blah){

  $s=1;
  $multiplefiles = $request->files;         
  foreach ($multiplefiles as $file) {
    $this->addFlash('success', $s++); // this always 1 why?
  }

}
```

i am sending multiple images using dropzone.js via Post to this function in symfony

> PS: super new to symfony

[image: example of post that sending]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to iterate through POST in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429256/how-to-iterate-through-post-in-symfony)

Comment: sorry my mouse bugged at left mouse it click multiple times by 1 click

Comment: Can you dump `$request->files` and post the content ?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$multiplefiles = $request->files->all();
```